# Installing Windows 10 or 8 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 MacBook Pro mid 2012

Tags: windows, bootcamp, partition

[image: output from the command diskutil list]

above is output from the command diskutil list

I've tried to install Windows 10 on my other internal HDD on my Mac to no avail. I already have 45 GB of partition on my SSD (where my macOS is) that's just sitting there due to Boot Camp Assistant not working properly.

I've tried a lot of things, I come all the way up to

*"We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one..."*

after converting my HDD to GPT.

I'm a long time Mac user. I'm up for advanced complicated solutions.

Comment: Where is the Boot Camp Assistant not working properly? Can you add the output from the command `diskutil list` to your question? I believe Windows is supposed to be installed to BIOS boot, therefore converting your HDD to GPT instead of MBR or hybrid would not make any sense.

Comment: Hello David, I tried Boot Camp Assistant, it only went through to partition page when I only check the second and third boxes. After that it installed the files, and partitioned. However, after that it showed the "MBR to GPT error" once I fixed it with the conversion from the command page, it gave the "We couldn't create a new partition... error."

Comment: I understand. So I will try to figure out a BIOS boot method and I will report my findings.

P.S. - Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Ok I understood the BIOS boot, I figured it out, and booted the Windows installer. However, during partition command I made a mistake and typed 5000 MB instead of 50000 MB and it gave an error and restarted into my macOS.  Now my Mac won't boot my usb again, though I can see the Windows BIOS alternative on my disk manager page (the page when option key is pressed right after the chime).

https://youtu.be/HQgbtIkHCFs

^ This is the tutorial I followed.

Comment: highsierra10136: Have you successfully installed Windows yet?

Comment: My Mac still won't boot my USB. When I turn on at startup disk manager (pressing option key right at the chime) it will show me my macOS disk and EFI Boot. When I select the EFI boot it freezes for a minute or so then restarts with my macOS. Is it possible that my Mac blocked my USB from booting?

Comment: It would appear the software on the USB is damaged. Have you tried recreating the software? How did you create the USB? Is the Windows Support Software on the USB?

Comment: I tried with the Windows Support Software and gdisk content but to no avail. I created the USB every other way I could find on YouTube. But furthest I got to was when I mounted the Windows .iso and transferred all the files, plus the Windows Support files downloaded separately from the Boot Camp Assistant > Action > Download and transferred to the USB. Since I made that partition command mistake, my Mac won't boot my USB. I will re download both Windows .iso and Windows Support Software from Boot camp Assistant, and try again. Will report my findings.

Comment: I downloaded a new Windows 10 .iso and followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/YkvLkRxPTB4

Still same issue. I don't know what else to do.